# Jquery error on rating system

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to follow a rating system tutorial to add a rating system to my website but there is an issue with the jquery, and was hoping somebody may be able to hightlight the error as i am fairly new with jquery, anyway any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
$('.star').click(function (){
var id = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('rating')[1];
var vote = $(this).index() 1;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:"save-vote.php",
data: "id=" id "&vote=" vote
});

})
```

it is showing that the error exists on this line:

```
var vote = $(this).index() 1;
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that line syntactically correct?

Comment: Why you've put '1' after using method?

Comment: It's actually a tutorial i am trying to follow and learn from, but it creates this error, i understand all of the other aspects of the tutorial but not the jquery section and there are two section which have similar errors.

Comment: You probably mean [this tutorial here](http://www.tutorialswindow.com/Web-Development/Javascript-tutorials/Creating-5-Star-Rating-System-Using-JQuery-PHP-MySQL-83.html). The corrected code is in the first comment on that page (missing `+`). By the way, it's not a very good tutorial - apart from the syntax errors, there's a glaring injection vulnerability in the PHP code.

Comment: it has nothing to do with `jQuery`... Your line has `syntax error` :)

Comment: Yes that was the tutorial, thanks for your comments and help, i guess i will go look for a better tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be something between `index()` and `1` The code you've posted is syntactically incorrect...

like

```
var vote = $(this).index() 1;
```

`+` or `-` etc....

What do you want to do exactly....?

Comment: It's just a rating system though  Juhana has pointed out that the tutorial is vunerable, so i think i will scrap it but thanks for you help